# Atmosphere - Nginx as https->http forwarder - websocket not working

Tags: java, asynchronous, nginx, websocket, atmosphere

I am using Nginx to transform https to http from client to server.

I have an atmosphere configuration working well in websocket without this forwarding.

Now if I switch to https with Nginx in the middle

```
var request = { url: "https://localhost/writever/chat",
                     contentType : "application/json",
                     logLevel : 'debug',
                     transport : transport ,
                     enableProtocol : true,
                     fallbackTransport: 'long-polling'};
```

Websocket connection fails after a timeout and downgrades to long-polling.

Would you know if it is possible to have websocket working under these conditions?

By the way, latest nginx 1.3 supports websocket proxying - still in dev mode. Does it have an impact on an AtmosphereHandler if such a method is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should not make a difference. But take a look at:

http://goo.gl/04g8F

You might want to add this header and see if that make a difference. I sincerely doubt, but try it.

-- Jeanfrancois

Comment: thx jf, actually it is working fine with nginx 1.3.13+ as it supports websocket proxy now. I posted my config here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178860/nginx-with-websocket-and-https-content-on-same-url